# Stepwise regression specific to variable transformations

Tags: r, regression

I have a (linear) regression model I am happy with. However, I want to automatically add in some transformations for the predictor variables and automatically select the best model with transformed variables based on adjusted R^2.

Are there any functions similar to `step` and `leap` which will do this? Here is an example using the built in `state.x77` dataset:

```
st = as.data.frame(state.x77)     
names(st)[c(4,6)] <- c("Life.Exp","HS.Grad")
fm = lm(formula = Life.Exp ~ Murder + HS.Grad + Frost, data = st)

transformations = list(function(x) sqrt(x), function(x) log(x))
```

Now I want to consider all transformations, in a stepwise manner, of the predictors in the model `fm` and pick the best model. E.g. e.g. in the first interation, compare

```
fm_sqrt_1 = lm(formula = Life.Exp ~ sqrt(Murder) + HS.Grad + Frost, data = st)
```

to
    fm_log_1 = lm(formula = Life.Exp ~ log(Murder) + HS.Grad + Frost, data = st)
to
    fm_sqrt_2 = lm(formula = Life.Exp ~ Murder + sqrt(HS.Grad) + Frost, data = st)
to
    fm_log_2 = lm(formula = Life.Exp ~ Murder + log(HS.Grad) + Frost, data = st)
to
    ...

Pick the best model out of these, and then do the same again for iteration 2.

Comment: I'm sure you can code this but it seems like a bad idea -- you're going to have some very serious data-snooping/multiple comparisons/contingency problems.  It's not multivariate, but I would consider the `acepack` package for this ...

Comment: Thanks, the documentation of ace seems to be along the lines of what I am looking for. But am I correct in saying that ace won't let you pick the transformations? I could probably look at the source code and modify it so that it can accept specific transformations...

Comment: And yep, agree with data-snooping problems.

Comment: Once you've made various transformations of the predictors, bundle them all up in a data frame. Then do `sample(names(df), N)` where `df` is the data frame containing all the various transformations and `N` is the number of variables you want to "retain". Fit a model with the selected variables. What you propose will result in a model with about as much going for it as the one fitted with the variables suggested by my approach.

Comment: One of the points of `ace` is that you select from a family of monotone transformations -- this is more coherent than picking from a discrete set.  I don't think modifying the code is going to be that easy (it calls FORTRAN code from the original implementation ...)

Comment: Thanks Ben. If you post your comments about `acepack` as an answer, I will accept it as the best one.